# wget not allowing access to file

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, wget

When I use wget to download a batch file from dropbox, then try to run it I get an error that says I do not have permissions to use this file. So far this only applies to batch files, I can wget and read/write all other files just fine.

edit: Using Windows 10 Home Premium x64

Comment: You need to set execute permission on file. `chmod +x \path\to\file`

Comment: @Misaz Please don't post answers as comments. Rather, post an answer as an answer.

Comment: @LouieK22 What operating system? What you say indicates a *nix-style OS, but "batch files" is a term commonly associated with the Windows ecosystem.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am using Windows 10 Home Premium x64

Comment: @Misaz The solution worked, post it as an answer and I think I can upvote it.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You are using Linux commands on Windows 10? Could you explain it more.

Comment: @Misaz Windows 10 now includes a "A full, Ubuntu-based Bash shell that can run Linux software directly on Windows. This is made possible by the new “Linux Subsystem for Windows” Microsoft is adding to Windows 10.". And of course there is cygwin as well as other bash implementations that run on Windows.

Comment: @Misaz http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set execute permission on file.

```
chmod +x \path\to\file
```